# matching files in while read with for loop

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, while-loop, xargs

I am trying to combine a for loop inside a while read command. If run alone, this for loop works as needed:

```
for file in *postp*/*; 
do;
ls $file/*/*/sequences/*/*_supercontig.fasta | xargs cat > My_New_File.txt; 
done;
```

However, I only want to cat the files (*.fasta) that are named based on a given input list (Files_to_cat.txt). Here is the code I am trying, but returns an empty file so I have something wrong.

```
while read -r name;
do;
    for file in *postp*/*; 
    do;
    ls $file/*/*/sequences/*/"$name"_supercontig.fasta | xargs cat > My_New_File.txt; 
    done;    
done<Files_to_cat.txt
```

Note the the list in Files_to_cat.txt matches the prefix of *_supercontig.fasta

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: make sure your `files_to_cat` file does *not* have `\r\n` line endings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't spot any mistake in the way you use `while read`.

You probably get this result because you use overwrite redirection `> My_New_File.txt`. If the last file which is `cat`-ed to `My_New_File.txt` is empty, then `My_New_File.txt` will be empty as well.

I expect what you want to do is either:

- Append to file: `>> My_New_File.txt;`
- Have a different file name for each output: `> "Copy_of_${file##*/}_$name"`

  - `${file##*/}` matches `*/` against the beginning of the string and removes it, so we get the basename of the file. We could as well do `${file//\//-}` to replace all slashes by dashes.

Comment: adding `> "Copy_of_${file##*/}_$name"` got me one step closer...it makes a copy of the *_supercontig.fasta files listed in the 'Files_to_cat.txt' but does not concatenate all the *_supercontig.fasta files

Comment: So what you want is just to append to the file. `>> My_New_File.txt`. Note you might want to delete it first (`rm My_New_File.txt`) so that you start with an empty file.